# c# find the same numbers in each column in a 2d matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, find

So, I have this task where I have to find the competitors who won in a tie.
Basically the input is a txt file, which has the number of competitors and the number of competitions in it's first row. The second and third rows are the maximum and minimum points. The rows after the third represent competitors and they have the amount of points they won.
I have to find the number of competitors who if they won, they won in a tie and their indexes.

One input:

```
6 8
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
8 4 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 5 7 6 6 6 6 5
6 6 6 5 5 5 5 6
8 6 8 7 7 7 7 6
8 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
8 6 6 6 6 6 6 1
```

The first row is 6 and 8 which means there is 6 competitors and 8 competition, the maximum points are 9 the minimum points are 5.

In this case the output is:

```
5 1 3 4 5 6
```

In the first column the winning point is 8, number 1 4 5 and 6 got 8 points which means they tied and should be added to the output, in the second column the winning point is 6, number 3 4 5 6 got 6 points so 3 should be added to the output too, and so on...

I've got this so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] fRow = Console.ReadLine().Split(' '); //splitting the first row to get N and M  
            int N = int.Parse(esor[0]);
            int M = int.Parse(esor[1]);
            int[] maxPoint = new int[M];
            int[] minPoint = new int[M];
            string[] maxP = new string[M];
            string[] minP = new string[M];
            maxP= Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            minP = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            {
                maxPoint[i] = Convert.ToInt32(maxP[i]);
                minPoint[i] = Convert.ToInt32(minP[i]);
            }
            int[,] matrix = new int[N, M];
            int[] s = new int[M];
            int mCol = 0; int mRow = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) //adding the points to the matrix
            {
                string[] row = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                for (int h = 0; h < N; h++)
                {
                    s[h] = Convert.ToInt32(row[h]);
                    matrix[mCol, mRow] = s[h];
                    mCol++;
                    if (mCol==N)
                    {
                        mCol = 0;
                        mRow++;
                    }
                }
            }


            int max = 0; //trying to find the greatest point in each column

            int[] winPoint = new int[M];
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            {
                for (int h = 0; h < N; h++)
                {
                    if (matrix[i, h] > max)
                    {
                        max = matrix[i, h];
                    }
                    if (h == N-1)
                    {
                        h = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And I got stuck here, I'm trying to find the greatest point in each column so they I could search for the same numbers in the colums and count the amount of ties, but I don't know how to do it. If someone could help me I'd really appreciate it, or if I should to it in a different way just tell me.

Comment: "but I don't know how to do it" what exactly is your problem?

Comment: every time I run it i get an error at the inner for loop: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: `IndexOutOfRange` happens when you try to access an array element that does not exist. E.g. your array has two items and you try to access the item at index 2 (= the third item). You should start your app in debug mode so it stops at this exception. Then you can see the variable values and that will explain why you get the exception.